# R discretionary printing of list elements by default

Tags: r, list

I have a list with many objects (data frames, R6 objects etc...) in it, I would like only 'some' of the lists elements to be printed, when the `print` method is called on the list. Which is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom `class` to your object and create a print method for this class:

```
x <- list(A=rnorm(5),B=sample(letters,100,replace=TRUE),C=mtcars)
class(x) <- c("myclass",class(x))
print.myclass <- function(x) {
                 print(list(A=prettyNum(x$A,digits=2), B=table(x$B)))
                 }
x
$A
[1] "-0.86" "-0.6"  "0.76"  "-0.2"  "-0.92"

$B

 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
 4  3  3 11  3  6  2  3  6  5  3  3  5  3  1  1  7  4  2  3  5  5  2  7  3
```